# Is it possible to decode A3 or A8 algorithm?

Tags: gsm

My question is pretty straightforward. I want to obtain the `ki` .
[image: A8 and A3 in GSM]

Assume that I have every piece of information `( rand, kc, sres )` except `ki`.

> So is it possible decode `ki` from A8 or A3 algorithm

And sorry I don't have required reputation to tag this question proper.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its always dangerous to say something is impossible in the security world as things evolve and new attacks emerge, but the A3/A8 algorithms, certainly in mobile communications and SIM/Authentication Center applications, are designed so that you cannot do what you are suggesting above.

There are documented attacks, some of which require a large number of tests against the device you are trying to extract the key from - this is why devices may be designed to restrict the number of requests in a certain time period.

There is a good overview in the following presentation (link correct at time of writing but name of presentation is 'T-79.514 Special Course on Cryptology' in case of difficulty):

- http://www.tcs.hut.fi/Studies/T-79.514/slides/S5.Brumley-comp128.pdf